# C++ trouble with outputing sum/avg

Tags: visual-c++

am taking a class of C++ and been asked to write a program that reads integers from a file.
first request is to output all of the integers in one line
and the second request is to output the average of the integers
ive tried what has been written in the book, and when I try to cout the sum or the average, it output the addition number by number  not just the total
how can I fix this? i want the simplest code possible, I dont want anything that we didnt take in class yet

```
    #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include <iomanip>
        #include <fstream>

        using namespace std;

            ifstream infile;
            ofstream outfile;

  int main()
 {
    int num;

    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;


    outfile.open("Answer.txt");
    infile.open("DataFile2.txt");

    infile >> num;

    while (infile)
    {
        outfile << num << " ";
        infile >> num;
    }
    infile.close();


    infile.open("DataFile2.txt");



    int sum = 0;
    while (infile)
    {
        double avg;
        infile >> num;
        sum = sum + num;
        avg = sum / 14;
        cout << endl << sum << avg;
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code.
You should declare the avg variable outside the while loop.
Also, you should calculate the average and print it after the while loop has finished looping.
Also you are dividing the sum by 14 (constant) which is not good, since you don't know how many integers are in the file.

The code should look something like this:

```
int sum = 0;
double avg;

while (infile) {    
    infile >> num;
    sum = sum + num;    
}

avg = sum / 14;
cout << endl << sum << avg;
```

Comment: well as I said am new to C++ and i almost know nothing :P
thnx for the quick answer and your code worked fine
thnx alot 
but i noticed something strange
when I manually did the sum of the integers in the files
it showed me different number than the one is being cout by the compiler
have any idea about it?

Comment: it looks like it is adding the last number twice to the total sum